# How to select rows whose partition is HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION?

Tags: mapreduce, hive, impala

hive inserts the bad column or record into HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION if we use dynamic partition.

My question is how to select the records in HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION?

something like this, but this will not do the trick.

```
select * from my_table where useDay=HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION
```

Thank you!

Comment: Query `show partitions {tablename}` or `hadoop dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/{dbname}.db/{tablename}/` to find out bad partition?

Comment: Hi, my concern is how to show all the rows in the default partition. For example, I can give the query something like this: select * from table_name where partition_column='jason'. But what if the partition is specified with __HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__，how can I do such query?

Answer (score 1):

Here is use case from my test tables:

```
hive> show partitions tt;
OK
p1=1/p2=a
p1=1/p2=b
p1=2/p2=c
p1=3/p2=__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__

hive> select * from tt where p1 = 3 and p2='__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__' ;
OK
3   NULL    NULL    3   __HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__
```

GL!